# Submit button redirect multiple page

Tags: php, html

Is there possible to redict multiple page after submit button? For example, user click 'Submit' then it will go to page1.php (same tab) and page2.php (another tab).

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="">
<button type="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
header("location:page1.php");
header("location:page2.php");
}
```

Comment: You cannot send two location headers. It's a bit of a hack, but you could `header("location:page1.php")` and then have page1 create a new tab via javascript for page2.php.

Comment: Yes it's possible, for example if you take over the submit with `onsubmit` in Javascript and simply submit to two windows. (Change the form target to `_blank` before you trigger the submit to push it into a new tab.) I'm assuming you want the post data in both. However, one action resulting in two pages opening is probably not very good UX design. Do you have a good reason to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. Only the page that submitted the request can receive a redirect response. The more complicated answer is if the first page opened the second page it can exercise some control over it via javascript. You could also use a websocket based mechanism to cause a page to reload similar to how react dev server works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of php and javascript.

Add a javascript function to the onsubmit of the form:

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
```

then, in your php, use your code to check for $_POST var and use:

```
header('Location: url');
```